# Does it have to be exactly five quarks to win?

Tags: pentaquark

I have sets in the detector like this:

> Green Up / Red Up / Blue Charm
>
> Anti-Green Anti-Up / Green Down
>
> Anti-Red Anti-Charm / Red Strange

The rules say the player needs to "assemble a set of 5 quarks at the detector," but this set of 7 contains a winning set. Is this game considered a win, or did I need to contain the quarks more concisely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extra quarks in the detector are irrelevant. The written rules say you win if at any time there is a pentaquark in the detector. If the pentaquark needed to be alone in the detector, the rules should state that explicitly. Fortunately, on their website they have a "How to Play" video made by the designer. In the video, he won with 6 quarks in the detector. The video is on YouTube at https://youtu.be/2WdbX97mUpQ and on the website at https://buttonshygames.com/pages/pentaquark

Answer (score 1):

You need exactly 5 quarks at the detector in order to win. While I am unable to find the rules online I have found other information that provides clarification of what the game is trying for.

[Pentaquark Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaquark)

> A pentaquark is a subatomic particle consisting of four quarks and one antiquark bound together.

With the name of the game being the same as a real subatomic particle it can be assumed that you are trying to create one in the game. Since the subatomic particle is defined by the specific amount of quarks it has it can be assumed that the game also needs to have that exact amount in order to be a winning combination.